# How to install pydelicious in Eclipse for Mac

Tags: python, eclipse

I trided this command "easy_install pydelicious" but got permission denied error. It also took me such a long time to find the right way and download the right pydelicious files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the newest pydelicious files here: https://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/downloads/list?can=2&q=pydelicious&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount
2. open Mac terminal and cd to the direction of pydelicious
3. open pydelicious file in the terminal and you will see setup.py file
4. use command "sudo python setup.py install" and the pydelicious will get installed.

Note: if you don't use sudo in the terminal command, you may get permission deny